# Правильно организовать БД

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день. Это скорее не вопрос, а совет.

Допустим, есть 2 таблицы: пользователи и задания. Так вот каждый пользователь выполняет задания чужих пользователей. Нужно вести учет, то есть какие задания пользователь выполнил, если он выполнил, то больше ему это задание не показывать. Так вот как правильно организовать все это? у каждого пользователя создать столбец и записывать через запятую те задания, которые пользователь выполнил, или же создавать отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Через отдельную таблицу - легче поддерживать и развивать в дальнейшем, возможность делать доп выборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользователи: `id, name`
Задания: `id,` `title`
Выполнение: `id_user, id_task, progress`

поле прогресс может быть булевым, тогда 0  - начал, но не завершил, 1 - начал и завершил.
Отсутствие строчки в последней таблице - "не принимался".

Если задание может выполнить только один человек, после чего оно считается выполненным для всех - третей таблицы не надо.

Comment: так так, немного не понял. есть таблица пользователей со столбцами id и name. есть таблица задание со столбцами id и title. А вот третья таблица.. что то не совсем я понял допустим есть эта таблица и юзер выполнил задание, то в эту таблицу добавиться запись где будет его id, также id задания и прогресс. Я так понимаю?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. Для ускорения можно повесить индексы на id_user и на id_task. Естественно, неуникальные. Зато пары значений уникальными будут всегда.

Comment: все ясно теперь. Теперь вопрос что за индексы? пример какой нибудь можете привести?

Comment: Это зависит от того какая именно у вас БД. Если MySql, то в ней изменение индексов производится командой add index или через phpMyAdmin - справа от каждой колонки таблицы в schema view есть четыре иконки ключ - primary key, лист с текстом - fulltext, U для unique и, наконец, просто index. Вот он-то вам и нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)
Буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

В такой схеме невозможен учет. Если пользователь1 начинает выполнять задание пользователя2, должна быть передача задания от пользователя1 пользователю2.

Comment: о чем это вы? есть 2 разные таблицы. никому ничего передавать не нужно